# В программе на Java таймер не выполняет поставленные задачи (не java.util.Timer и не javax.swing.timer)

Tags: java, таймер

Здравствуйте, у меня есть программа, проверяющая знания по арифметическим действиям. В классе сложения есть 3 метода (по крайней мере, которые относятся к вопросу): "new1" (для создания рандомного числа в 1-ую JLabel), "new2" (для создания рандомного числа в 2-ую JLabel) и метод "proverka" (проверяющий правильность ответа). Мне нужно чтобы ответ был дан пользователем не более чем через 20 секунд, если же ответ не был дан, то я забираю значения из 1-ой JLabel, 2-ой JLabel и JTextArea. После теста работает ли таймер как нужно, у меня возникла проблема - по истечению времени методы не вызываются и ничего не меняется (числа в JLabel остаются такими же). Подскажите как это можно исправить?

**P.s Пояснения к коду: fc - 1-ая JLabel, sc - 2-ая, answer - JTextArea, notRv - переменная неправильных ответов, nowrec - рекорд сейчас, notRight - Jlabel выводящая кол-во неправильных ответов, ranswer - правильный ответ, panswer - ответ пользователя из JTextArea, panel - JPanel**

```
//Методы для создания новых чисел
public void new1() {
    String f = Integer.toString(1 + (int) (Math.random() * 500));
    fc.setText(f);
}

public void new2() throws Exception {
    String s2 = Integer.toString(1 + (int) (Math.random() * 500));
    sc.setText(s2);
    answer.setText("0");
    Thread t = new Thread();
    for(int i = 20; i >= 0; i --) {
        t.sleep(1000);
        if (i == 0) {
            proverka(fc.getText(), sc.getText(), answer.getText());
            new1();
            new2();
        }
    }
}
//Метод проверки 
protected  void proverka (String a, String b, String answerp) {
    int p = Integer.parseInt(a);
    int p1 = Integer.parseInt(b);
    int ranswer = p + p1;
    int panswer = Integer.parseInt(answerp);

    if (ranswer != panswer) {
        notRv++;
        nowrec++;
        notRight.setText("Количество неправильных ответов: " + Integer.toString(notRv));
    }       
    if(notRv == 3) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Чтож, Вы проиграли...");
        //zapis_Recorda(nowrec);
        panel.remove(next);
    }
}
```

Comment: а как у вас организована работа с gui, в том же потоке? У вас gui блокируется во время работы кода?

Comment: @Виктор Нет, все работает. Поток создан исключительно для того, что бы создавать задержку.

Comment: ок а где точка входа в этот кусок кода?